# clisp: how can I find a specification of complex

Tags: class, complex-numbers, clisp

I am writing a LISP program to deal with line integrals on complex numbers.I wonder if somebody can tell me where can I find a specification of **class complex** in **clisp**

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers are part of the Common Lisp standard. You can read about them in the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm). The most relevant chapters are:

- [2.3.2.3 Syntax of a Complex](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_cbc.htm),
- [2.4.8.11 Sharpsign C](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhk.htm),
- [12.1.5 Complex Computations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/12_ae.htm),
- [22.1.3.1.4 Printing Complexes](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_acad.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If this is, indeed, a question about [GNU CLISP](http://clisp.org), you might also want to take a look at the [CLISP-specific docs](http://clisp.org/impnotes/num-concepts.html#complex-comp).